# I need to extract the Hours or timings data from the drop down in facebook page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to extract Hours data from the drop-down menu from a Facebook page. I have tried to select its CSS selectors
I can fetch the timings data but it is not coming in aligned

```
span_xpath = "//span[contains(@class, 'x1q0g3np') and contains(@class, 'xohu8s8')]"
span_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, span_xpath)
button_inside_span = span_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'i')
button_inside_span.click()
hours = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@aria-label="Hours"]'))).text
```

Output:

Hours
Hours
Closed now
Monday
CLOSED
Tuesday
16:00 - 23:00
Wednesday
CLOSED
Thursday
16:00 - 23:00
Friday
11:30 - 23:59
Saturday
11:00 - 00:00
Sunday
11:00 - 23:00
Popular times
MON
TUE
WED
THU
FRI
SAT
SUN
6AM
9AM
12PM
3PM
6PM
9PM
12AM
3AM
Services
Outdoor seating
Roadside collection
In-store collection\

I want it to be like this

Hours
Monday CLOSED
Tuesday 16:00 - 23:00
Wednesday CLOSED
Thursday 16:00 - 23:00
Friday 11:30 - 23:59
Saturday 11:00 - 00:00
Sunday 11:00 - 23:00

facebook url is : https://www.facebook.com/theanchorvenice/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJaEp.png)

Comment: I am new to webscrapping. So, please bare with my limited knowledge about it

Answer (score 0):

**.xifccgj:nth-child(6) .x78zum5**  - I checked it show we have 3 web element, i.e. it is not able to find the element.
Use index like (//span[@class='x1q0g3np xohu8s8'])[1] in xpath

**select from drop down**

namespace

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
```

web element

```
Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
```

make sure it's visible

```
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("ANTARCTICA");
```

you can select from variours method

```
drpCountry.selectByValue("234");
drpCountry.selectByIndex(0);
drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("ANTARCTICA");
```